# Ansible: gocryptfs doesn't ask for password

Tags: encryption, fstab, ansible

When I use Ansible to create all kinds of remote mounts that need a SSH password, the `ansible-playbook` command simply asks for them when I run it. However, when I want to create a gocryptfs mount, I get

```
FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Error mounting /mnt/test: Reading Password from stdin\nGot empty Password from stdin\n"}
```

Here is my playbook task:

```
- name: Decrypt
  ansible.posix.mount:
    src: gocryptfs#/mnt/.enc_test
    path: /mnt/test
    state: mounted
    fstype: fuse
    opts: nofail
```

How do I make sure the password is always asked? I know I can supply the option `-extpass`, but what program would I use there to get a default terminal prompt when I run the playbook first and create the fstab entry, and an input like dm-crypt on booting?

Answer (score 1):

You can't expect the module [*mount*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/mount_module.html#ansible-posix-mount-module-control-active-and-configured-mount-points) to respond to the prompts like the module [*expect*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/expect_module.html#ansible-builtin-expect-module-executes-a-command-and-responds-to-prompts) does.

There are more options on how to solve this problem. The first and the second option below don't create an entry in */etc/fstab*

1. Use the module *expect* if you want to provide [*gocryptfs*](https://github.com/rfjakob/gocryptfs/blob/master/Documentation/MANPAGE.md)
   with the password interactively
2. Use the module [*command*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/command_module.html#ansible-builtin-command-module-execute-commands-on-targets) and try the parameter [*stdin*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/command_module.html#parameter-stdin)
   or provide *gocryptfs* with the password in the options:

- -extpass CMD [-extpass ARG1 ...] Use external program ... to return the password on stdout
- -passfile FILE [-passfile FILE2 ...] Read password from the specified plain text file

3. Provide the module *mount* with the password file. See [example](https://github.com/rfjakob/gocryptfs/blob/master/Documentation/MANPAGE.md#fstab)

```yaml
  ansible.posix.mount:
    src: /mnt/.enc_test
    path: /mnt/test
    state: mounted
    fstype: fuse./usr/local/bin/gocryptfs
    opts: nofail,passfile=/tmp/password
```

<sup>(not tested)</sup>

4. If you have problems with the module *mount* use [*lineinfile*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html#ansible-builtin-lineinfile-module-manage-lines-in-text-files) and create the entry in */etc/fstab* on your own. Create and notify a handler *mount -a*.

See: [(Re-)starting a systemd unit with user input on Ansible](https://superuser.com/questions/1722412/re-starting-a-systemd-unit-with-user-input-on-ansible)